# Extjs - how to load comboxboxes data before the form data

Tags: asynchronous, extjs, combobox, request

I have a form that contains several comboxes that their data is coming from the server.
I need to load all of the combobox's data before the form data is loading (from the server).
If Extjs had allow synchronized requests, I would make every combo as synchronized, and after that loading the form data.
but as far as i know, everything needs to be done via callbacks, which makes the form a bit "re-use-less"
Any idea how to salve it?
Just to make it clear, I am talking about a situation of editing an employee details for example, which its form data contains:
first_name, last_name, city_id(bombo),country_id(combo) 
And loading the combobox data of city_id and country_id  is critical for the selectedValue issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combo_store.load();

combo_store.on('load', function(st, records, options)
{
    // callback called after data loading in combo
    // you can load other data
});
```

Comment: thanks. this is a callback that makes the entire form ugly, on every form i have 10-20 combos, that can make it vary difficult, thanks

Comment: you can use common callback-function that count callback calls, when it richs 10-20, it means that all combo data loaded.

Comment: Thanks, that not so clean, I am building an application with many forms like that, I know that it can make troubles... Thanks